# can this be imported to xcode and be made for mac to use?

Tags: xcode, macos

https://github.com/cinemassacres/SteamDesktopAuthenticator

if not is there a way so that i can make this for mac?

Comment: Good luck getting DirectX running on a Mac.

Comment: is there way to make fix it so that it can be on xcode?

Comment: No. It has too many Windows dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you referenced is written in Microsoft's Visual C#, and it uses DirectX.

Both only run on Windows (or with Wine/Mono), so good luck with natively compiling this on Mac OS.

Even when using compatibility layers such as Wine, I doubt you'll be able to compile this. If you manage to get an already compiled version, your chances with [Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX) and Mono may be higher, but I won't make any assumptions on how well it works.